# Facebook social plugin localisation

Tags: localization, facebook-social-plugins

As instructed on the FB Developer site, I've integrated the social comments plugin on our website and changed the lang parameter to Dutch.  However this does not seem to affect the interface.  The plugin is still in English.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_BE/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Example:
http://www.miramiro.be/nl/festival/programma/die-verdammte-fanfare-cabrio

Anyone an idea?

Many tnx
Gino

Answer (score 0):

Visit Facebook Developer page and go to edit the App Settings. In there, select the app you wish to edit and visit the 'AppDetails' tab. In there, change your primary language to Dutch and it should work.

Comment: ok, tnx for your answer ... since I have a multi-lingual website, does this mean I need to create a different app per language?

Comment: changed it but without any result ... BTW, social plugins can be used without creating an App, no?